# dynamic variable to href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below href's which is present in html page and i want to pass parameter 'abc' to few url's with value computed based on javascript.
Below is example:

```
<a href="www.google.com?abc=123">one</a>
<a href="www.yahoo.com?abc=123">two</a>
<a href="www.youtube.com">three</a>
```

So i want to add value to those href's which have parameter as 'abc' and value will be calculated in javascript. Is there a way it can be added to href link or do we need to use jquery to build the url?

Comment: Can you be more clear about your question? Do you mean you want to change the href of a link with some value from some where (please define it)?

Comment: Are those `href`s generated dynamically (not typed by you)? Either way.... Yes, it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setAttribute` & `getAttribute` to append the query param to the existing `href`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(item) {
  var getHref = item.href;
  var newHref = getHref + "?abc";
  item.setAttribute('href', newHref)

})
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" id="one">one</a>
<a href="www.yahoo.com" id="two">two</a>
<a href="www.youtube.com" id="three">three</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try if following script help you:

```
var number = 100; //Assume this coming from javascript calculation

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(item) {
   if(item.href.indexOf("?abc") > -1){
      item.setAttribute('href', item.href + number)
   }
})
```

And your markup wher have only 'abc':

```
<a href="www.google.com?abc=">one</a>
<a href="www.yahoo.com?abc=">two</a>
<a href="www.youtube.com">three</a>
```

Comment: suppose abc is not the first parameter but i have other parameters before abc but only i want to add it to abc. "www.google.com?def&abc="

Comment: i got the solution, i did something like this:- document.querySelectorAll('a[href$="&abc="]'){